# request.getQueryString() returns value but request.getParameter() return null for the key

Tags: servlets

I am passing some parameters as part of url, I am able to see the value when I use `request.getQueryString()`. For instance, `keyword=dual%20element%w20fuse`. But when I use `request.getParameter("keyword")` it's returning `null`.

This is happening only for some keywords. For instance: if I pass the keyword as   `xyz`, `request.getParameter("keyword")` correctly returns `xyz`.

Why am I getting `null` for those keywords?

```
String queryParams = request.getQueryString();
String keyword = request.getParameter("keyword");
```

Comment: Do you have any filters in your application?

Comment: Yes we do have some filters

Comment: I don't see the keyword  coming to filter itself.  What could be the possibility? Its just a migrated code and the same keyword works fine in legacy but not in cloud.